# CORS Error, I'd searched but i cannot found one. Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, vuejs2

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors');
User = require('../server/models/userListModel');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Userdb', {useNewUrlParser: true})

const routes = require('../server/routes/userListRoutes');
routes(app);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
console.log('Connected to Express/MongoDB Server')
```

---

I have cors but i still have this error on create
Failed to load htttp://localhost:3000/users: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: facepalm.. `http` not `htttp`

Comment: Im so sorry about that typo. Thanks btw. I will keep an eye on my dizzy hands. Thank youuuu.

Comment: no worries, just fresh eyes..